# DirectShow Sample cutscene.cpp crashes when switching app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx, directshow

There is a cutscene.cpp sample code in the Windows SDK (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388355(v=vs.85).aspx ) which showcases how you can use DirectShow in order to show a fullscreen video as cutscene. However if you press the Windows keys, Alt-TAB etc. and the app loses focus while the video is playing, it will hang and crash. 
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Hangs and crashes suppose you can provide more information, call stacks in particular. That would be a good Q improvement.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure what or how I can provide this. The example just crashes when it loses said focus.